# AngularJS filter by variable object property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In AngularJS, you can filter an array of objects by an object property like this:

```
var filteredItems = $filter('filter')(items, {someObjProp: someValue});
```

My question is, how do i filter without hardcoding the 'someObjProp' - I want this to be a variable like:

```
var filteredItems = $filter('filter')(items, {arr[0].prop: someValue});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Setup the object in advance

```
var obj = {};
obj[arr[0].prop] = someValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument passed to the filter can be a function expression:

```
var filteredItems = $filter('filter')(items, function(value,index) {

   //you can do whatever you want in here with your 
   //object (value), just return true or false to fail or pass the filter

   return (value.arr[0].prop === someValue);
});
```

Simply return `true` for all objects that pass the filter and return `false` for objects that get filtered out.

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter